# Importing PSA animation to my model only moves head but is still distorted

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode, unreal-engine

ive imported a PSA animation from UE viewer and the head only moves but is upside. I also tried this on other models and it completely distorts and stretches those models. It seems that it just ruins the model everytime i import the PSA animation. I reset the transformations always and i honestly have no idea how to solve this, i cant think of anything. I've used RIGIFY to rig my character model

[image]